# Remote with jconsole to sow performance of jboss 7.0 eap

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I ready install jboss 7.0 eap on windows server 2016. Now i want to use jconsole to remote from other PC in LAN to show jboss performance but cannot remote. Please everyone help guide me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific about the issue you are having?

Comment: My issue is cannot remote to jboss 7 eap vai jconsole or jmc.
Please help show me the configuration that enable remote on jboss.

Comment: Hi Chantha, it seems you are new in SO, so welcome!

A better way to go about it is to show what have you done so far, what errors you are getting, so we can help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes i done all for jboss. But just want to remote from other PC in LAN to view jboss performance.